# Android: How to set default orientation when acitvity supported landscape and portrait

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developing a app it has two activity. A1 only supported portrait, A2 supported two orientation.
When the device is portrait and then I switch to A2. The layout of A2 is fine. But the device is landscape and then switch to A2, the layout confused. The first width and height are exchanged.

I setup the UI like this:

```
onCreate () {
  DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics(); 
  getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

  setupUI(dm.widthPixels, dm.heightPixels);
}
```

Have anyway to set the default orientation or other way can resolve this problem? Thx.

Answer (score 6):

add this tag to your activity in `Manifest`

```
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can force an activity orientation in manifest like this:

```
<activity 
    android:name=".A1" 
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
</activity>
```

This way, Activity `A1` will always be in portrait orientation, even if you switch back to it from Activity `A2`